# Is there any easy way to add spaces on left of the first line in an edittext

Tags: android

Is there any easy way to add spaces before the start of Sentence in edittext. Suppose if I want to Type

```
 "Hello my name is Zohan.
  I am from kochi"
```

It should be displayed like

```
"           Hello my name is Zohan.
"I am from kochi.
```

To be more specific , is there anyway to provide **padding for the first line only in a multiline supported ediText ?**

Obviously padding feature is not doing the task.

Comment: it will be difficult to find multiline in editext and if found than it will not add space when you start writing in edittext

Comment: wait a minute... you wana center first line? then use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AlignmentSpan.Standard.html

Comment: Try SpannableString

Comment: you can do this by appending \t\t with text on textchange listner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText` , this will trigger when you add your first line to your `EditText`, also i added a boolean value and this will triggered only one time:

Add this `boolean` in your global scope : `boolean isSpaceAdded=false;`

```
mEdittextContent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(!isSpaceAdded) {
                if (mEdittextContent.getLineCount() > 1) {
                    mEdittextContent.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String editstring= mEdittextContent.getText().toString();
                    mEdittextContent.getText().clear();
                    mEdittextContent.setText("       "+editstring);
                    isSpaceAdded=true;
                    mEdittextContent.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

> What is the point here :

You must remove `TextChangedListener` before change `EditText's` text. Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use LeadingMarginSpan

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan.Standard.html

`public void setIndent(int length) {
    //First remove the original indent(s)
    for (LeadingMarginSpan span : getText().getSpans(0, getText().length(), LeadingMarginSpan.class)) {
        getText().removeSpan(span);
    }
    mIndent = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(length, 0);
    getText().setSpan(mIndent, 0, 0, 0);
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString = editText.getText().toString();
myString = "        " + myString;
editText.setText(myString);
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to add some whitespaces at the beginning of the text of the `EditText`. Thererfore you would need to add an TextChangedListener like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();
        //I'm adding four whitespaces in this example...
        if (!text.substring(0,4).equals("    ") {
             text = "    " + text;
        }
        yourEditText.setText(text);
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might sound a little noob way of doing it but you can try adding some Space in the beginning of `Edittext` programmatically `beforeTextChanged()`, and when extracting the text out of Edittext, you can subString it to remove the spaces you add in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the lines in the textbox, append spaces to the lines needed, then set the text of te textbox to the text you updated.